# Применить макрос ко всем файлам excel в папке

Tags: excel, vba, макросы

Добрый день, не пойму никак в чем проблема. Макрос вроде должен пробежать по всем файлам, сделать изменения и сохранить их, но применяется только к книге из которой запускаю. В чем может быть дело?

```
Sub Auto_Write_In_Books()
    Dim sFolder As String
    Dim sFiles As String
    Dim li As Long

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        If .Show = False Then Exit Sub
        sFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    sFiles = Dir(sFolder & Application.PathSeparator & "*.xls*")
    On Error Resume Next
    Do While sFiles <> ""
        Workbooks.Open sFiles

        ' начало макроса '
        Cells.Replace What:="с/", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
            :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
        Cells.Find(What:="исполнитель", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
        ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Range("A1").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "ООО ""ТЭК""Интеллект Логистик"""

        ' конец макроса '
        ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
        sFiles = Dir
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: А файл, из которого Вы запускаете этот макрос, не первым в списке стоит? Если так, то макрос выполняется в этом файле, затем файл закрывается и останавливает работу макроса. Добавьте еще условие на проверку, равно ли `sFiles` текущей книге. В этом случае книгу не закрывать (да и открывать не стоит, иначе книга переоткроется, и запуск макроса так же остановится)